# Lock iPhone and iPad Screen programmatically

Tags: ios

I want to lock screen iPhone and iPad programmatically
I have searched a lot but didn't get proper idea. I have found one app Lock me but it is not worked on after iOS 7.

here is that link
https://github.com/neuroo/LockMeNow

as per my search I think we are able to implement this functionality using private api and using kiosk mode.

Comment: Have you tried the code snippet in that project's readme?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I have tried

Comment: is there a problem? what happens when you try it?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I have tried there source code. In application didbecomeactive there is one if condition which not given true. and application aborted. I have tried also using condition true statically. application run properly but not lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can programmatically lock the iPhone or iPad from you application. that not full fit the apple policy and its guide line. In `iOS` app development we can not handle any API that out of the application. Apple not make any API for lock screen that you fire from your native app.

Other things is you are attached one link in your question. that clearly write the limitation that:

> This application can obviously not be accepted (as is) on the Apple Store, and that's mostly why I put it here. If you want to use the application, you will need a developer cert (or a jailbroken device and using the iDevice build toolchain).